# How to prevent line breaks while keeping width of column constant

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I am creating an Excel using Apache POI. I set the width of the column using `setColumnWidth(colNo, width)` method. Now, when I populate large data, what happens is that when it exceeds the column width, the API adds a `\n`, new line character.

Thus if I insert:

> ```
>  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
> industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
> since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
> scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
> ```

It gets converted to:

> ```
> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the 
> printing  and typesetting
> industry. Lorem Ipsum has been  the 
> industry's standard dummy text
> ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
> printer took a  galley of type
> and scrambled it to make a type  spec
> imen book.
> ```

The issue is if I copy and paste the text from this cell to word, these extra line breaks due to fixed width are retained.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: *when it exceeds the column width, the API adds a \n , new line character* it is supposed to.

Comment: Also, where is your code?

Comment: "when it exceeds the column width, the API adds a \n , new line character": I doubt that. Please show a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce that behavior.